# Google Maps Plugin return coordinates

Tags: plugins

I just need to return the latitude and longitude of my Google Maps marker.  I do not want to make a request to Google, nor do I need to display a map with javascript.  I need to create markers inside of blog entries and only return the coordinates.

Can the Google Maps plugin do this?  Can I pass the lat and lng to text fields when i save the entry?

Comment: Which google maps plugin are you referring to?

Comment: Google Maps for Craft : https://github.com/objectivehtml/Google-Maps-for-Craft/

I would open to using something else, as long as I could add a marker within the publish page.

Answer (score 4):

Was out of town so couldn't answer this question until now. With Google Maps for Craft you can do so like this:

```
{% set marker = entry.yourMapField.getMarker(0) %}

{{ marker.lat }} {{ marker.lng }}
```

Or you can loop through all the markers on the map like this:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('news') %}

    {% for marker in entry.yourMapField.getMarkers() %}

        {{ marker.address }}<br>

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

https://github.com/objectivehtml/Google-Maps-for-Craft/wiki/Getting-Address-From-Map-Markers

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know about ObjectiveHTML’s Google Maps plugin, but this is easy to do using Lindsey DiLoreto’s [Smart Map](https://craftpl.us/plugins/smart-map/) plugin, which comes with an “Address” field type.

Per the “[Using an Address Field](https://craftpl.us/plugins/smart-map/docs/using-an-address-field)” documentation, you can output latitude and longitude values like this:

```twig
Latitude: {{ entry.address.lat }}<br />
Longitude: {{ entry.address.lng }}
```

(In that example, `entry` is an entry that has an Address field called `address`.)

Comment: Just used Smart Map, the best plugin IMO out there to manage maps.